# Add pictures to plot using defined anchor points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using Python and would like to know what the easiest way, using any library, would be to add images to a plot using defined points on the image to connect to specific points on the plot.

So say I have a plot like so, where I know all the begin and end coordinates of the segmetns:
[image]

and a picture like so:
[image]

What would be the easiest way to add the picture onto each segment of the plot so that the red dots on the picture are anchored to the coordinates of the segment? Also, I need to be able to change the orientation of the picture i.e. narrow part facing up or down.

This is my class code for generating the line segments using an orientation vector i.e. ["TOP", "BOTTOM", "TOP", "TOP", "BOTTOM",...]

```
class Limb:

    delta_L = 0.3
    theta = radians(8)

    def __init__(self, size=15, length=1):
        self.length = length
        self.size = size
        self.XY = np.zeros((2, size+1))

    def build(self, orient_vec):

        self.curvature = 0

        delta_length = self.length + Limb.delta_L
        theta_vec = np.zeros((self.size+1))

        if len(orient_vec) != self.size:
            exception_string = (
                'Orientation vector size must equal limb size.\n' +
                'Orientation vector size:\t{}\n'.format(
                    len(orient_vec)) + 'Limb size:\t{}\n'.format(self.size)
            )
            raise Exception(exception_string)

        else:
            for ind, seg in enumerate(orient_vec, 1):
                if seg == "TOP":
                    angle = theta_vec[ind-1] + Limb.theta

                    self.XY[0, ind] = self.XY[0, ind-1] + \
                        (delta_length * cos(angle))
                    self.XY[1, ind] = self.XY[1, ind-1] + \
                        (delta_length * sin(angle))

                    self.curvature += Limb.theta

                    theta_vec[ind] = theta_vec[ind-1] + 2*(Limb.theta)
                elif seg == "BOTTOM":
                    angle = theta_vec[ind-1] - Limb.theta

                    self.XY[0, ind] = self.XY[0, ind-1] + \
                        (delta_length * cos(angle))
                    self.XY[1, ind] = self.XY[1, ind-1] + \
                        (delta_length * sin(angle))

                    theta_vec[ind] = theta_vec[ind-1] - 2*(Limb.theta)

                    self.curvature -= Limb.theta
                else:
                    upto = ind
                    break

                upto = ind

            if self.XY.sum() <= 0:
                return
            else:
                self.XY = np.delete(self.XY, np.s_[upto:], 1)
```

So to reproduce the plot run this:

```
from . import Limb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

limb = Limb()

orientation_vector = ["TOP", "BOTTOM", "TOP", "TOP",
                      "BOTTOM", "TOP", "BOTTOM", "TOP", "TOP", "BOTTOM", "TOP", "BOTTOM", "TOP", "TOP", "BOTTOM", ]

limb.build(orientation_vector)

segs = limb.XY.shape[1]

points = limb.XY

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([0, 0], [-2, 2], color='black')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

ax.plot(points[0, :], points[1, :], color='red')

ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you looking to do something similar I used this to help [`imshow_affine`](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/api/demo_affine_image.html#api-example-code-demo-affine-image-py):

Step by step:
1. Open image
2. Calculate line segment midpoints
3. Use `imshow_affine` to add image to plot
4. Determine if narrow part is at top or bottom because one needs to add 180 degrees to the rotation
5. Using `matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around` and `matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().translate` the image is rotated and positioned correctly. Remember to set this transform with `.set_transform`

Final plot:
[image]